# sub field aggregation group by order by in elasticsearch

Tags: elasticsearch

I am unable to find the correct syntax to get an aggregation of a sub object ordered by a count field.

A good example of this is a twitter document:

```
{
  "properties" : {
    "id" : {
      "type" : "long"
    },
    "message" : {
      "type" : "string"
    },
    "user" : {
      "type" : "object",
      "properties" : {
        "id" : {
          "type" : "long"
        },
        "screenName" : {
          "type" : "string"
        },
        "followers" : {
          "type" : "long"
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

How would I go about getting the Top Influencers for a given set of tweets? This would be a unique list of the top 10 "user" objects ordered by the "user.followers" field.

I have tried using top_hits but get an exception:

> org.elasticsearch.common.breaker.CircuitBreakingException: [FIELDDATA]
>   Data too large, data for [user.id]

```
"aggs": {
    "top-influencers": {
      "terms": {
        "field": "user.id",

        "order": {
          "top_hit": "desc"
        }
      },
      "aggs": {
        "top_tags_hits": {
          "top_hits": {}
        },
        "top_hit": {
          "max": {
            "field": "user.followers"
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
```

I can get almost what I want using the "sort" field on the query (no aggregation), however if a user has multiple tweets then they will appear twice in the result. I need to be able to group by the sub object "user" and only return each user once.

**---UPDATE---**

I have managed to get a list of the top users returning in very good time. Unfortunatly it still isnt unique. Also the docs say top_hits is designed to be a sub agg..., I am using it as a top level agg...

```
"aggs": {
    "top_influencers": {
      "top_hits": {
        "sort": [
          {
            "user.followers": {
              "order": "desc"
            }
          }
        ],
        "_source": {
          "include": [
            "user.id",
            "user.screenName",
            "user.followers"
          ]
        },
        "size": 10
      }
    }
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
{
    "aggs": {
        "GroupByType": {
            "terms": {
                "field": "user.id",
                "size": 10000
            },
            "aggs": {
                "Group": {
                    "top_hits":{
                        "size":1, 
                        "_source": {
                                "includes": ["user.id", "user.screenName", "user.followers"]
                        },
                        "sort":[{
                            "user.followers": {
                                "order": "desc"
                            }
                        }]

                     }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

You can then take the top 10 results of this query. Note that normal search in elastic search only goes up to 10000 records.